# Including one module in another module with variable

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, rtl

I need to implement this code to synthesize and do so that `xor21` and `and21` will work separately.

```
module top(
 input a, b, x,
 output c
);

always @(a or b or x)
begin
    if(x)
       xor21 x1 (.a(a), .b(b), .c(c));
   else
      and21 a1 (.a(a), .b(b), .c(c));
end
endmodule
```

However, I get the following error:

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:1575 Instantiation is not allowed in sequential area
>   except checker instantiation

How do I go about designing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to go back to basics.

Verilog is a hardware description language, not a programming language. Your code is describing hardware.

Let's see what your code is trying to infer:

```
module top(
 input a, b, x,
 output c
 );
```

Ok, we have a module. That's all fine. Now what does it do?

```
always @(a or b or x)
begin
    if(x)
       xor21 x1 (.a(a), .b(b), .c(c));
   else
      and21 a1 (.a(a), .b(b), .c(c));
end
```

That code says "Whenever `a`, `b`, or `x` changes: If `x` is high, instantiate a new piece of hardware called `xor21`, otherwise instantiate a different piece of hardware called `and21`".

Hmm, that means that if the value of `x` changes, bits of your hardware suddenly disappear, and other bits of hardware appear from nowhere. This **cannot happen**. The whole design needs to be known when the design is synthesized.

In otherwords, you cannot instantiate a module in a procedural block.

---

Instead, you need to think about what you hardware you need. You decide, well I need an `and21` module, and an `xor21` module. So lets instantiate one of each:

```
module top(
 input a, b, x,
 output c
 );

 wire xor21_output;
 wire and21_output;

 xor21 x1 (.a(a), .b(b), .c(xor21_output));
 and21 x1 (.a(a), .b(b), .c(and21_output));
```

Cool. Now we have a our module, and it contains our two submodules. Now we need to work out the behaviour of the output `c`.

Well, if `x` is high, we want the output from `xor21`, and if `x` is low, we need the output from `and21`. So that means we need a multiplexer. Well, we can either do this in continuous assignment using the ternary operator (`?`), or we can use an always block. Let's look at both. First the ternary:

```
assign c = x ? xor21_output : and21_output;
```

Then the always block (see note):

```
always @ (x) begin
    if (x) begin
        c = xor21_output;
    end else begin
        c = and21_output; 
    end
end
```

And voila. We now have a module with the required behaviour, in which the required hardware is known when the design is synthesised.

---

(note) - if you are assigning a value in an procedural block (such as always or initial), the target must be a storage type, such as `reg`. You cannot assign a `wire` type in a procedural block. So we would have to change the module definition to `output reg c`.

Comment: I want that xor21 and and21 will work separately

Comment: You can't. The best you can have is a logic block with three inputs a,b and x  which implement the function. For that you can try `assign c = x?a^b:a&b;` An FPGA will use a single LUT to make that.

Comment: @AndranikAvetisyan you cannot have hardware suddenly change. It would be like having a switch that desoldered an IC from a circuit board and then soldered a different one in. Instead you **must** have all hardware present already, and can then simply switch between them.

Comment: In fact both the design above, and the one-liner @Oldfart suggested, will both end up compiling into a single lookup table in the FPGA anyway.

Comment: there is the only example in large design that bad version.
can I use `define  or (i don't know everything ) for solved that issue because in IC design that possible

Comment: You can use parameters to disable bits of hardware (using generate blocks), however you must remember that this will happen before synthesis. Hardware cannot be controlled by a run-time variable.